# How to prevent Mapbox GL JS FlyTo animation from being interrupted?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl

If a user clicks, swipe scrolls on mobile, or interacts with the map in any way, the flyTo animation is canceled. How can I stop that?

Or at the very least, jump to the destination?

Comment: On mobile devices my flyTo is being interrupted on a mobile device after typing an address in the geocoder box. It doesn't happen on desktop so I'm assuming it's because the keyboard is changing the display size.?

Answer (score 2):

On my mobile device, flyTo fails the instant my keyboard hides after geocoder input. It appears the onscreen keyboard display and hiding interferes with the flyTo animation. This workaround corrected my issue:

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  animate: false
});

var geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({
  accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
  flyTo: false
});

geocoder.on('result', function(ev) {
    map.jumpTo({
        center: ev.result.center
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to disable all map events via Mapbox API and interaction with the canvas element with some css:

```css
.mapboxgl-canvas {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```